# Why does PayPal's sample API order code generate CS1061, CS0117 & CS0246 errors?

Tags: asp.net, paypal, webforms, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

### Introduction

I tried updating one of my existing ASP.NET Web Application projects to incorporate PayPal's sample .NET code for working with the PayPal REST APIs, but hit several problems and so decided to start from scratch with a new project.

This was created within VS 2019 using the C# version of the ‘ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)’ project template, with Web Forms.

I then used the NuGet Package Manager to install the PayPal Checkout SDK (PayPalCheckoutSdk). This was Step 1 in [Set up PayPal SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/set-up-sdk/). Step 2 of that procedure was to copy PayPal's C# code for "setting up the environment" and paste it into a code page I called **PayPalAPI.cs**. PayPal told me to save this in the "same directory as the SDK". I initially thought this meant the solution Packages folder, but that doesn't work. Putting it in the project's Bin folder (which also contains the SDK dll) does work, though I have been advised this is not desirable, so PayPalAPI.cs is now stored in the root of my project.

I also changed the namespace in PayPalAPI.cs to match that of my project, added an assembly reference to System.Runtime.Serialization, and inserted my own Sandbox ClientID and Secret.

The next step was to create a blank C# page called **PayPalOrder.cs**, into which I copied PayPal's sample code for creating an order, as defined [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/create-order/). The namespace was changed to match my project and several HTTP errors were fixed by adding a using directive for PayPalHttp and installing the System.Net.Http package.

Copies of both PayPalAPI.cs and PayPalOrder.cs are shown below (though Stackoverflow's code insertion tool doesn't seem to cope well with using directives and namespace statements).

### My problem

I get the following errors in PayPalOrder.cs.

- 'Order' does not contain a definition for 'intent'
- 'PurchaseUnit' does not contain a definition for 'Amount'
- 'OrderRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Intent'
- 'PurchaseUnitRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Amount'
- 'AmountWithBreakdown' does not contain a definition for 'Breakdown'
- 'PurchaseUnitRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Shipping'
- The type or namespace name 'ShippingDetails' could not be found

There are probably some missing assembly references and/or using directives, but I'm struggling to guess what they might be.

I have never used PayPal's API before and I don't have a very deep understanding of ASP.NET, so I may have made some basic errors, but any guidance would be much appreciated.

### PayPalAPI.cs

using System; using PayPalCheckoutSdk.Core; using PayPalHttp; using System.IO; using System.Text; using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

namespace MyTestCSharpWebApp2
{

public class PayPalClient
{

```
    public static PayPalEnvironment environment()
    {
        return new SandboxEnvironment("PAYPAL-SANDBOX-CLIENT-ID", "PAYPAL-SANDBOX-CLIENT-SECRET");
    }

    /**
        Returns PayPalHttpClient instance to invoke PayPal APIs.
     */
    public static HttpClient client()
    {
        return new PayPalHttpClient(environment());
    }

    public static HttpClient client(string refreshToken)
    {
        return new PayPalHttpClient(environment(), refreshToken);
    }

    /**
        Use this method to serialize Object to a JSON string.
    */
    public static String ObjectToJSONString(Object serializableObject)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonWriter(
                    memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8, true, true, "  ");
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(serializableObject.GetType(), new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings{UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true});
        ser.WriteObject(writer, serializableObject);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(memoryStream);
        return sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

### PayPalOrder.cs

```
using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Threading.Tasks; using PayPalCheckoutSdk.Core; using PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders; using PayPalHttp;
```

namespace MyTestCSharpWebApp2
{

```
public class CreateOrderSample
{

    //2. Set up your server to receive a call from the client
    /*
      Method to create order

      @param debug true = print response data
      @return HttpResponse<Order> response received from API
      @throws IOException Exceptions from API if any
    */
    public async static Task<HttpResponse> CreateOrder(bool debug = false)
    {
        var request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
        request.Prefer("return=representation");
        request.RequestBody(BuildRequestBody());
        //3. Call PayPal to set up a transaction
        var response = await PayPalClient.client().Execute(request);

        if (debug)
        {
            var result = response.Result<Order>();
            Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", result.Status);
            Console.WriteLine("Order Id: {0}", result.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("Intent: {0}", result.Intent);
            Console.WriteLine("Links:");
            foreach (LinkDescription link in result.Links)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}: {1}\tCall Type: {2}", link.Rel, link.Href, link.Method);
            }
            AmountWithBreakdown amount = result.PurchaseUnits[0].Amount;
            Console.WriteLine("Total Amount: {0} {1}", amount.CurrencyCode, amount.Value);
        }

        return response;
    }

    /*
      Method to generate sample create order body with CAPTURE intent

      @return OrderRequest with created order request
     */
    private static OrderRequest BuildRequestBody()
    {
        OrderRequest orderRequest = new OrderRequest()
        {
            Intent = "CAPTURE",

            ApplicationContext = new ApplicationContext
            {
                BrandName = "EXAMPLE INC",
                LandingPage = "BILLING",
                UserAction = "CONTINUE",
                ShippingPreference = "SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS"
            },
            PurchaseUnits = new List<PurchaseUnitRequest>
    {
      new PurchaseUnitRequest{
        ReferenceId =  "PUHF",
        Description = "Sporting Goods",
        CustomId = "CUST-HighFashions",
        SoftDescriptor = "HighFashions",
        Amount = new AmountWithBreakdown
        {
          CurrencyCode = "USD",
          Value = "230.00",
          Breakdown = new AmountBreakdown
          {
            ItemTotal = new Money
            {
              CurrencyCode = "USD",
              Value = "180.00"
            },
            Shipping = new Money
            {
              CurrencyCode = "USD",
              Value = "30.00"
            },
            Handling = new Money
            {
              CurrencyCode = "USD",
              Value = "10.00"
            },
            TaxTotal = new Money
            {
              CurrencyCode = "USD",
              Value = "20.00"
            },
            ShippingDiscount = new Money
            {
              CurrencyCode = "USD",
              Value = "10.00"
            }
          }
        },
        Items = new List<Item>
        {
          new Item
          {
            Name = "T-shirt",
            Description = "Green XL",
            Sku = "sku01",
            UnitAmount = new Money
            {
              CurrencyCode = "USD",
              Value = "90.00"
            },
            Tax = new Money
            {
              CurrencyCode = "USD",
              Value = "10.00"
            },
            Quantity = "1",
            Category = "PHYSICAL_GOODS"
          },
          new Item
          {
            Name = "Shoes",
            Description = "Running, Size 10.5",
            Sku = "sku02",
            UnitAmount = new Money
            {
              CurrencyCode = "USD",
              Value = "45.00"
            },
            Tax = new Money
            {
              CurrencyCode = "USD",
              Value = "5.00"
            },
            Quantity = "2",
            Category = "PHYSICAL_GOODS"
          }
        },
        Shipping = new ShippingDetails
        {
          Name = new Name
          {
            FullName = "John Doe"
          },
          AddressPortable = new AddressPortable
          {
            AddressLine1 = "123 Townsend St",
            AddressLine2 = "Floor 6",
            AdminArea2 = "San Francisco",
            AdminArea1 = "CA",
            PostalCode = "94107",
            CountryCode = "US"
          }
        }
      }
    }
        };

        return orderRequest;
    }

    /*
       This is the driver function that invokes the createOrder function
       to create a sample order.
    */
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateOrder(true).Wait();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: There are some slightly different samples in the github for the sdk here: https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NET-SDK/tree/develop/Samples. Maybe try some of those. The ones on the website might be outdated?

Comment: @erastl
Thanks for the suggestion. I will check out that GitHub solution later if I fail to get anywhere with PayPal's own code.